# removeAttr from select with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I know this has been asked quite often, but I wouldn't ask if I would've found my answers there. I have a very basic scenario:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hideFirst').hide();
    $('#pkw_neu').on("change", function() {
        if($(this).val() == 1) {
            $('.hideFirst').fadeIn();
            $('#eigenanteil').attr("required", "required");
        }
        else {
            $('.hideFirst').fadeOut();
            $('#eigenanteil').removeAttr("required");
            // $('#eigenanteil').prop("required", false);
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, I simply want to have a field `required`, if another field was set to yes (1) before. The events are triggering (fading in and out) - but for some strange reason, i always end up with `required=""` (which is apparently parsed as `required="required"`) when I switch back to no (0).

Working on IE 7

```
<select name="pkw_neu" class="form-control" id="pkw_neu">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Ja</option>
    <option value="0">Nein</option>
</select>

<select name="eigenanteil" class="form-control" id="eigenanteil">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Ja</option>
    <option value="0">Nein</option>
</select>
```

Any workarounds or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```

Comment: I don't have problems with setting "required", i have problems with unsetting it. Also that wouldn't help at all. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You should set it as false:

```
$('#eigenanteil').prop('required',false);
```

Comment: tried that as well, also in the opening example (commented out)

Comment: have you check that $('#eigenanteil') exists in your code and you didn't use this id more than once? your code is correct

Comment: Yes, I checked that. It is working as expected in Chrome + Firefox as well. Only IE is making trouble

Comment: oh, IE gives a lot of problems like that! Maybe you can try $('form').f5() after the removal

Answer (score 0):

Simple one

Make the input required to false (ie) `$("input").prop('required',false);`

Thanks